# How can i get data by using "with" laravel relationship function by a condtion?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

[this is my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfMtC.png) => table image

```
//This is my controller
public function listUserStripeActionableRequests(Request $request) {
        return $model = UserRequest::whereNull('deleted_at')
            ->with('oldPackage')
            ->get();
}


userRequest.php

public function oldPackage() {
    return $this->hasOne(Package::class, 'id', 'old_package_id');
}
```

I need to get data according to package_type in the table
if package_type == 1 then i need to get data from Package::class,
if package_type == 2 then from AddOnsPackage::class then model function like :-
`$this->hasOne(AddOnsPackage::class, 'id', 'old_package_id');`

How can i use single query to get data accordingly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```php
class UserRequest extends Model
{


    public function package()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Package::class, 'id', 'old_package_id');
    }

    public function addon()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(AddonPackage::class, 'type', 'add_on_type');
    }

    public static function sorted()
    {
        return static::whereNull('deleted_at')
            ->get()
            ->map(function ($record) {
                if ($record->package_type === 1) {
                    $record->load('package');
                } elseif ($record->package_type === 2) {
                    $record->load('addon');
                }

                return $record;
            });
    }
}
```

Then in the controller you can do

```php
public function listUserStripeActionableRequests(Request $request)
{
    return $model = UserRequest::sorted();
}
```

Comment: it's not recommended to put a condition like whereNull('deleted_at'), in a scope called scopePackageType, this condition should be outside this scope, or at least, rename your scope to fit this condition.
I recommend moving this 'where' to another scope

Comment: Hi thanks for commenting, I need to get data according to package_type check my table ( https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfMtC.png ) . If package_type == 1 then i need to get data from Package::class, if package_type == 2 then from AddOnsPackage::class then model function like :- $this->hasOne(AddOnsPackage::class, 'id', 'old_package_id'); .

Comment: I guess the scope can be named as `byPackageType` for better readability. When using soft deletes I guess the deleted_at can be included in the scope, I personally don't mind it. However it can also be excluded from the scope.

Comment: @ShifasHassan Then you probably also need to define a relationship to the `AddOnsPackage`. Will update my answer for demo

Comment: Actually we are not passing any request for package_type. We want to take package_type from the table and do the desired relationship according to it.

Comment: I don't quite understand, when you get a request in controller method you will fetch a record from the database for UserRequest based on some condition right?

Comment: yeah we need to get data according to the package_type https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfMtC.png .check out my table in first row package_type = 2 so we need to get data from AddOnsPackage. If 1 then Package. and for each row like that

Comment: we are not passing any request for package_type we are getting package_type 1 or 2 from table

Comment: SO in that case maybe you can try defining your relationships based on package_type condition. Let me update the answer

Comment: this didnt work cause we are doing where condition package_type from Package model and AddOnsPackage . package_type  didnt exist in this models ,,, we need package_type from our current model UserRequest.

Comment: Yeah sorry my bad. Give me few minutes

Comment: @ShifasHassan I have updated my answer to get the result you desire, pls check and let me know if what I understand as your requirement is correct and that the above answer get it done.